# MySQL MySQL-CC error 1193 when connecting to recently updated database

Tags: mysql

The MySQL database that I have connected to in the past has been updated to version `5.6.20.`

Now, when I try to connect with `MySQL-CC` I get the following error reported:

```
Error 1193: Unknown system variable 'SQL_MAX_JOIN_SIZE'
```

Has this variable gone missing in the update?

Or was it missed out by the person doing the update here?

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Thanks for the link and info, Barmar.  Does that mean that MySQL-CC can no longer be used as it has "sql_mas_join_size" hard coded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of changes in MySQL 5.6 is at

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-nutshell.html

Under **Removed Features** it says:

> The **sql_max_join_size** system variable. Use **max_join_size** instead.

A number of other system variables have been removed and replaced with new variables. I'll bet they were deprecated in previous releases, but I haven't checked.

Comment: Thanks for the link and info, Barmar.  Does that mean that MySQL-CC can no longer be used as it has "sql_max_join_size" hard coded?

Comment: I don't know what MySQL-CC is. Maybe you should check whether there's a new version of it that addresses this issue.

Comment: MySQL-CC is the tool that came before MySQL-Workbench.  It is a legacy product and won't be developed any more.  It is my preferred MySQL tool.

Comment: Then I guess you have to stick with MySQL 5.5.

Comment: Sadly, that's not an option. The DB has been updated.  Unless there is a work-around I'll have to use a different tool.  Thanks for your help, Barmar.

Answer (score 0):

I had a batch file to invoke mysql with -U, and removing -U solved this problem.